# HOW TO COMPUTE MULTIPLE DATETIME TEXTBOXES

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have 8 textboxes dimmed as datetime time in and timeout for Monday to Thursday now I have another set of 4 textboxes when I enter time in and timeout the 4 textboxes show the total hours rendered for each day including the late(mins) now I need to add all of the inputs in the 4 textboxes so it would show up to another textbox labelled as total hours (including the late) and another one that is labeled total late (mins later per day). I have tried to dim all of the 4 textboxes as datetime and used timespan.

```vb
'this is the code in the button labeled as compute hours
'Monday
    Dim t1 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim t2 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = t2.Subtract(t1)
'TEXTBOX10.TEXT IS THE TOTAL HOURS RENDERED IN MONDAY
    TextBox10.Text = ts.Hours.ToString("0") & ":" & ts.Minutes.ToString("00")

    ' Tuesday
    Dim t3 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(TextBox5.Text)
    Dim t4 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(TextBox4.Text)
    Dim ts1 As TimeSpan = t4.Subtract(t3)
'TEXTBOX9.TEXT IS THE TOTAL HOURS RENDERED IN TUESDAY
    TextBox9.Text = ts1.Hours.ToString("0") & ":" & ts1.Minutes.ToString("00")

    ' Wednesday
    Dim t5 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(TextBox7.Text)
    Dim t6 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(TextBox6.Text)
    Dim ts2 As TimeSpan = t6.Subtract(t5)
'TEXTBOX8.TEXT IS THE TOTAL HOURS RENDERED IN WEDNESDAY
    TextBox8.Text = ts2.Hours.ToString("0") & ":" & ts2.Minutes.ToString("00")

    ' Thursday
    Dim t7 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(TextBox12.Text)
    Dim t8 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(TextBox13.Text)
'TEXTBOX3.TEXT IS THE TOTAL HOURS RENDERED IN THURSDAY
    Dim ts3 As TimeSpan = t7.Subtract(t8)
    TextBox3.Text = ts3.Hours.ToString("0") & ":" & ts3.Minutes.ToString("00")
```

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand.. Can you explain once again, slowly, what is the problem and desired output? Thanks in advance

Comment: im creating a payroll system now i use textboxes for the time in and time out then another textbox where the total hours would display

Comment: for example textbox1.text = monday time in textbox2.text = monday time out and textbox3.text = monday total hours now when time in is 08:00 and time out is 17:00 it will display 9.00 hours.

Comment: now i have 4 textbox for time in (monday to thursday) and 4 textbox for timeout and another 4 for total hours(per day) what i want is to add all the 4 textbox for total hours (per day) and display the output in another textbox lbeled as total rendered hours

Comment: As a best practice, you should give meaningful names to your form controls and variables. Your code should be as self-documenting as possible—use proper namings to explain your intent to the reader (even if the reader is only you).

Answer (score 0):

See my code (just for monday and tuesday)

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim t1 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim t2 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = t2.Subtract(t1)
    'TEXTBOX10.TEXT IS THE TOTAL HOURS RENDERED IN MONDAY
    TextBox10.Text = ts.Hours.ToString("0") & ":" & ts.Minutes.ToString("00")

    ' Tuesday
    Dim t3 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(TextBox5.Text)
    Dim t4 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(TextBox4.Text)
    Dim ts1 As TimeSpan = t4.Subtract(t3)
    'TEXTBOX9.TEXT IS THE TOTAL HOURS RENDERED IN TUESDAY
    TextBox9.Text = ts1.Hours.ToString("0") & ":" & ts1.Minutes.ToString("00")

    'MAGIC HERE :D
    TextBox13.Text = (ts + ts1).ToString()
End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

PS: just count ts, ts1, ts2, ts3 - cast into string and show in your total textbox :)